# How to find the minimal basis of an invariant ring?

Tags: representation-theory, galois-theory, invariant-theory

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $\neq 2$. Let $C_4=\langle\sigma\rangle$ act on $K^2$ by $\sigma (a,b)=(-b,a)$. This translates to $\sigma:s\mapsto t, t \mapsto -s$ on $K(s,t)$, and it is "easily seen" that $K(s,t)^{C_4}=K(u,v)$ for

$$u=\frac{s^2-t^2}{st}$$

and

$$v=s^2+t^2$$

Another example is $K(s,t)^{C_3}=K(u,v)$, where $C_3=\langle\sigma\rangle$ acts on $K^2$ by $\sigma(a,b)=(-b,a-b)$, so $\sigma:s\mapsto t,t\mapsto -s-t$, and so

$$u=\frac{s^2+t^2+st}{st(s+t)}$$

and

$$v=\frac{s^3-3st^2-t^3}{st(s+t)}$$

I understand why these are homogeneous invariants, but why do they necessarily form a minimal basis of $K(s,t)^G$?

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you need/want, but Galois theory tells us that $[K(s,t):K(s,t)^G]=|G|$. So if you can show that in both cases A) $u,v$ are invariant, and B) $[K(s,t):K(u,v)]=|G|$, then you can conclude that $K(u,v)=K(s,t)^G$.

Comment: If $G$ is a finite group, and $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space with a basis $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, then the invariants $K(x_1,\ldots, x_n)^G$ are a finitely generated algebra (Hilbert) which is generated by polynomials of degree at most $|G|$ (Noether) if the characteristic of $K$ is greater than $|G|$. But I also am not sure this is what you need/want, because it's unclear if you are asking a general problem or a very specific problem about your particular examples.